# What is the Block Size of ETC2-compressed texture?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

What is the block size of a `GL_COMPRESSED_RGB8_ETC2` and `GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA8_ETC2_EAC` texture ?

I was using  `((w+3)/4)*((h+3)/4)* 8` for `GL_ETC1_RGB8_OES`, but can't find anything about ETC2 (the Khronos documentation is not very clear about it).

Comment: Did you take a look at the framework from http://humus.name/ ? He might have it in his source code ( Framework 3, maybe 2 ).

Answer (score 3):

```
    // ETC1
    { 4, 4, 8, COMPRESSED_ETC1_RGB8_OES },

    // ETC2 / EAC
    { 4, 4,  8, COMPRESSED_R11_EAC },
    { 4, 4,  8, COMPRESSED_SIGNED_R11_EAC },
    { 4, 4, 16, COMPRESSED_RG11_EAC },
    { 4, 4, 16, COMPRESSED_SIGNED_RG11_EAC },
    { 4, 4,  8, COMPRESSED_RGB_ETC2 },
    { 4, 4,  8, COMPRESSED_SRGB8_ETC2 },
    { 4, 4,  8, COMPRESSED_RGB8_PUNCHTHROUGH_ALPHA1_ETC2 },
    { 4, 4,  8, COMPRESSED_SRGB8_PUNCHTHROUGH_ALPHA1_ETC2 },
    { 4, 4, 16, COMPRESSED_RGBA8_ETC2_EAC },
    { 4, 4, 16, COMPRESSED_SRGB8_ALPHA8_ETC2_EAC },
```

First two values are block size (eg. 4x4) the third value is BytesPerBlock. The fourth value is compression mode. This is from a table I use for handling all compressed formats that exist.

I removed values which are not useful for this answer (compression and decompression function pointers and preferred pixel formats for source/destination data, sRGB, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The OpenGL ES 3.0 specification includes the statement: `A texture compressed using any of the ETC texture image formats is described as a number of 4 x 4 pixel blocks` in Section `C.1 ETC Compressed Texture Image Formats`.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW ETC2 extends ETC1 by making use of some, otherwise unused, bit patterns as described by Strom et al in "[Texture Compression using Invalid Combinations](http://www.jacobstrom.com/publications/StromPetterssonGH07.pdf)". (See also the Graphics Hardware [Slides Presentation](http://www.graphicshardware.org/previous/www_2007/presentations/strom-etc2-gh07.pdf)):

The block sizes are therefore the same.

Answer (score 1):

The block sizes are documented here: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glCompressedTexImage2D.xhtml

In particular:

- GL_COMPRESSED_RGB8_ETC2 = ceil(width/4) * ceil(height/4) * 8
- GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA8_ETC2_EAC = ceil(width/4) * ceil(height/4) * 16